# Loop with separate iterations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to calculate the variable h with the following system of equation in MATLAB. What could be a proper way to write it?

```
h(1) = 1 - z(1);
h(2) = 1 - h(1) - z(2);
h(3) = 1 - h(1) - h(2) - z(3);
h(4) = 1 - h(1) - h(2) - h(3) - z(4);
h(5) = 1 - h(1) - h(2) - h(3) - h(4) - z(5);
h(6) = 1 - h(1) - h(2) - h(3) - h(4) - h(5) - z(6);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `diff` which takes the difference between any two elements.

```
z = [1 4 5 7 8 3];

h = [0 -diff(z)];
%     0    -3    -1    -2    -1     5
```

How we determine to use `diff` is that we can easily write out the terms and see that most things cancel

```
h(2) = 1 - h(1) - z(2)
h(2) = 1 - (1 - z(1)) - z(2)
h(2) = 1 - 1 + z(1) - z(2)
h(2) = z(1) - z(2)
```

Comment: Sorry, why cumsum? In each equation it has a different value.

Comment: Hi, yes. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should mostly work. The trick is to setup an array with z in it.

```
h=[]% empty array
h(1)=1-z(1)
for counter=2:N
    h(counter)=1-cumsum(diff(h(1:counter-1)))-z(counter)

end
```

Comment: Hi, no its not working. It only takes one value of h on right hand side, but number of h variable to be subtracted increases with increasing order.

Comment: You should look into the use of the diff command along with cumulative sum to calculate the cumulative difference of h.

Comment: This expands `h` every time through the loop which is *extremely* inefficient

Comment: Completely agree. I like your solution a lot better too.

Comment: I tried the edited version, now I have an error that says the number of elements are not the same.